# Why my pointers get invalidated, if I don't use vector.reserve()?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, vector

I have small piece of code, which containts a vector of class(Vector2) for 2-dimensional vertices and a vector of template class DynamicLine which takes Vector2 type object for argument.

```
std::vector<Vector2> m_coords;
std::vector<DynamicLine<Vector2>> m_lines;
Vector2 *lineVec = NULL;





 bool draw = true;
 case DrawingWidgetState::ADD_VERTEX_SELECTED:{
                for(auto it = m_coords.begin(); it != m_coords.end(); it++)
                     if(it->distanceFrom(Vector2(event->x(), event->y())) < 20 && !m_coords.empty()){
                        draw = false;
                        break;
                     }

                if(draw){

                    if(event->x() < m_mainWindow->width() - 10 && event->x() >= 10
                            && event->y() < m_mainWindow->height() && event->y() >= 10) {


                        m_coords.push_back(Vector2(event->x(), event->y()));
                        update();
                    }
                }
                break;

            }


case DrawingWidgetState::ADD_LINE_SELECTED:{
                for(auto it = m_coords.begin(); it != m_coords.end(); it++)
                    if(it->distanceFrom(Vector2(event->x(), event->y())) < 10){

                        if(!i){
                            lineVec = &(*it);
                            i++;
                        }

                        else{

                            m_lines.push_back(DynamicLine<Vector2>(lineVec, &(*it)));
                            i = 0;

                        }
                        update();
                        break;
                    }
                break;

            }
```

Problem is next. For example if I add two vertices and a line between them then everything works fine. But if I now add another vertex(m_coords.push_back(Vector2(event->x(), event->y()));) then the line dissaperas and values in m_lines vector are changed to very random big numbers. I read something about pointers getting invalidated. If you push new values to vector then some will eventually get expanded. I also fixed my problem using vector::reserve, but since I'm sure I'm not doing this right could anyone please explain me how should I use vector::reserve and why I need to do that?

Comment: 1) Fix your indentation. 2) create [mcve]. 3) Try to use debugger, to step through your code, while inspecting the values of the variables at each step. In that order.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at your code closely, but it seems like it's the reallocation of the vector that's causing you trouble.

A vector always keeps track of two sizes: its capacity, and the number of objects it contains. If you do a push_back, and its capacity was already at maximum, it will copy itself to another location in memory with more space and a bigger capacity. Your pointers are probably still pointing at the original location.

When working with vectors, it might be better to keep indices instead of pointers.

EDIT: you iterate over an array on which you may perform insert operations. That shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly simple. When you `push_back` and the `vector` does not have enough `capacity` it needs to allocate more memory and copy (or move) your elements to the new location. This invalidates any iterators/pointers pointing to the old elements (they are now just pointing to the old freed memory block) which means they basically point to garbage - so you have to get new iterators after the `push_back`.

Calling `reserve` tells the vector to allocate a block of memory up-front so that any *subsequent* `push_back` can be guaranteed to not need a reallocation (if you stay within the reservation (actually `capacity`)) and thus won't invalidate iterators/pointers to elements.